# Multiple labels in a Section Row

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitableview

since a couple of days i'm trying to print two strings coming from an array of data, parsed from a xml file coming from my server (that was long :D). The problem is that i only managed to print one of the two strings. i made my researches and find a pointer on a technic but i can't managed to make that technic work if someone could help me please. here is my code :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
}
for(UIView *eachView in [cell subviews]){
    [eachView removeFromSuperview];
}

UILabel *lbl1 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
[lbl1 setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12.0]];
[lbl1 setTextColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
int storyIndex = [indexPath indexAtPosition: [indexPath length] - 1];
lbl1.text = [[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: @"creation_date"];
NSLog(lbl1.text);
[cell addSubview:lbl1];
[lbl1 release];

UILabel *lbl2 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
[lbl2 setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12.0]];
[lbl2 setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
lbl2.text = [[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: @"name"];
NSLog(lbl2.text);
[cell addSubview:lbl2];
[lbl2 release];

//Used to do this ---> int storyIndex = [indexPath indexAtPosition: [indexPath length] - 1];
//[cell.textLabel setText:[[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: @"creation_date"]];
return cell;
```

}

Comment: Why dont you use textLabel and detailTextLabel of cell ?

Comment: Because i don't know any other way, i'am very new to objective c.

Comment: If you dont want to do much customization use them as these are provide in iOS by default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem I see is that you are adding subview directly to cell. You should add it to cell.contentview like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 160, 50);
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:label];
    [label release];
}

// Get a reference to the label here

label.text = @"9:00am";

return cell;
}
```

Also I strongly suggest to create subclass for UITableViewCell.

Comment: Sorry it Worked like magic :D !!! i just have the two label one on another, i will try to fix it. Anyway, Thank youuu :D !!!!!

Comment: You need to set them appropriate frames, but If you use Storyboard you can prototype cell easily with interface builder

Comment: yep i just ajusted the frame  it looks beautiful :D. But do you know why the letters gets thicker and thicker as i scroll in the simulator device ? It seems like it is re-calculating every thing again and again. Thank you for your answers :)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to dynamically create labels for a cell in this way you are better off just using a custom table view cell that already has the two labels positioned as you want. You can then set the text for those labels directly.

Looking at your code, I also recommend that you move to ARC rather than MRC and also read up on the documentation for table views; you don't need to check for a nil value returned from the reuse queue in this case, or if you are using correctly configured custom cells on a storyboard.

Comment: Yes i saw that in my researches but its way to hard for me right now, i dug it, and will continue in order to understand Cells very closely. Thanks for your answer and concern.